# "Index was out of range" Error at await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-blob-storage, bearer-token

I'm followed this [tutorial](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/07/upload-a-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-web-api/) to upload/download blobs from Azure Blob Storage.

The Code works perfectly until I implemented the Bearer token Authentication(OAuth)

I've got the error while Uploading any files from the postman.The below is error description.

> {
>       "Message": "An error has occurred. Details: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection.\r\nParameter name: index" }

However, the files were successfully uploaded in my Blob Account.But still, the error continuously occurs for me.

I've attached the image of the error details that obtained while debugging.

[image]

The area where I've prompted the error in my Upload Controller

```
 try
            {
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest($"An error has occured. Details: {ex.Message}");
            }
```

My AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider Class which is inherited from the MultipartFormDataStreamProvider

```
public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {


                if (parent == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));
                if (headers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(headers));


            // Generate a new filename for every new blob

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            headers.ContentLength = 0;

            if (headers.ContentType != null)
                {
                    // Set appropriate content type for your uploaded file
                    blob.Properties.ContentType = headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                }

                this.FileData.Add(new MultipartFileData(headers, blob.Name));

                return blob.OpenWrite();         
        }
```

For Implementing the Oauth2.0 authentication I've just added the Startup .cs and Startup.Auth.cs in my project (with the required NuGet packages *Owin*)

Here's my StackTrace

> *at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)    at System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider.<ExecutePostProcessingAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at DemoAzureStorage.Controllers.UploadController.d__1.MoveNext()*

Comment: Share the call stack/stack trace.

Comment: @rene updated the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I have created a test demo(all installed package is newest one) on my side, it works well.

I used asp.net web api with google login and AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider as your shows.

My upload file controller codes as below:

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    private const string Container = "mycontainer";

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }


        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Container);
        var provider = new AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(imagesContainer);

        try
        {
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"An error has occured. Details: {ex.Message}");
        }

        // Retrieve the filename of the file you have uploaded
        var filename = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault()?.LocalFileName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            return BadRequest("An error has occured while uploading your file. Please try again.");
        }

        return Ok($"File: {filename} has successfully uploaded");
    }
}
```

AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider Class:

```
public class AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    private readonly CloudBlobContainer _blobContainer;
    private readonly string[] _supportedMimeTypes = { "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg" };

    public AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer) : base("azure")
    {
        _blobContainer = blobContainer;
    }

    public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        if (parent == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));
        if (headers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(headers));

        if (!_supportedMimeTypes.Contains(headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower()))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only jpeg and png are supported");
        }

        // Generate a new filename for every new blob
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        CloudBlockBlob blob = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        if (headers.ContentType != null)
        {
            // Set appropriate content type for your uploaded file
            blob.Properties.ContentType = headers.ContentType.MediaType;
        }

        this.FileData.Add(new MultipartFileData(headers, blob.Name));

        return blob.OpenWrite();
    }
```

The result as below image shows:

[image]

If possible you could create a test project and push it to the github or one drive for us to reproduce your issue.

Packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Knockout.Validation" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="knockoutjs" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Sammy.js" version="0.7.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I've published my project on Github.https://github.com/jayendranarumugam/MyProject

Comment: I've used Password grant_type.So please use the below access_token.{
    "access_token": "qOErEnLSbDjQW8XaUnSEImDNRTe8WRVJHbqXEUQxJw4EiqHoybw4Jc4gBYJkClORNCprnPbJxJ0WGumBcq-i4TMom-HxOBGgYgneYbTUKw5zyrWSwTEdtPsfjNzzYxCtcwSj4a9tEEj_j8czKcrauM9lhJMHcx4p9jS-nWkAAZepvJKJx8fqQUZgyo4tjysDSpNJBTAsTMgw2Z8xZ3QXGW06OzYW2LeOkNUmFp0PWY2sj0Suykgz0G2Lw7KXBar7okFHLV9KtZPArAWsOfFAvi-c84y6TjqzZkZnU5n5jmAy_Z3A3j1Ahww7Kz4p-p6lu7dYFw",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 60899,
    "refresh_token": "a868cb78-4773-4fbf-888e-38a6b0a11700"
}

Comment: I couldn't run your application on my side. Could you share a building complete application? Besides, I found your Owin version is 2.1, I suggest you could update to 3.1 and try again.

Comment: Changing the Owin version doesn't work. Wait I'll share you a build complete app

Comment: Sorry, Github is totally new to me.So, i uploaded my whole project in one-drive.https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsEgl90kVfyygYciOroDxFTAWr_B6Q                   Let me know if you have any issues on viewing this

Comment: Don't forget to add your blob storage account name and key in the web.config file. Also the container name in the uploadcontroller class

Comment: After reproducing your issue, I found the reason. I found your Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi version is 5.0.0. I guess this may have something wrong with the MultipartFormDataStreamProvider class. I suggest you could try to upload the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi version to 5.2.3. It will work well.

Comment: Ok,will try and let you know the status

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thanks, mate could you please tell how you find this error.So, in future, I'll also keep that in my mind